# how to build pandas data frame faster from elastic scroll result?

Tags: python, json, elasticsearch

In my case, I have to read 1 million ~ 2 million json results from elastic by scroll. However,it is quite slow to build pandas data frame from the result(100 thousands records, about 10s). list my code below:

```
while (scroll_size > 0):
    frame = pd.DataFrame.from_dict([document['_source'] for document in page["hits"]["hits"]])
    frame['L7P'] = frame['L7P'].astype('category')
    appended_data.append(frame)
    page = es.scroll(scroll_id = sid, scroll = '1m', request_timeout = 30)
    # Update the scroll ID
    sid = page['_scroll_id']
    # Get the number of results that we returned in the last scroll
    scroll_size = len(page['hits']['hits'])
```

Comment: It seems that your code currently works, and you are looking to improve it. Generally these questions are too opinionated for this site, but you might find better luck at [CodeReview.SE](//codereview.stackexchange.com/tour). Remember to read [their requirements](//codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) as they are a bit more strict than this site.

Answer (score 0):

Pandas is not exactly a speed demon for large datasets. If you want something much faster, use [Datatable.](https://towardsdatascience.com/an-overview-of-pythons-datatable-package-5d3a97394ee9#:~:text=The%20results%20show%20that%20datatable,takes%20seconds%20for%20the%20same.)